# Visual editor is not working in wordpress 4.1.1

Tags: php, wordpress

I got the issue in my wordpress site. It is not showing the visual editor in page. It was working before. I did not update or install any thing on site. I have deactivate all plugins and activate the default theme but problem is not fixed. I have also change tinymice file in wp-include folder and add the following code in wp-config but problem is still there

```
       define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Please let me know how I can fix it?

Comment: Look at your browser's developer console, do any error messages appear there? If yes, what are they?

Comment: I have checked that. It is not showing any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by the specific user meta value added in the newest versions of WordPress. Could you check your `wp_usermeta` table and check if your current user has the key `rich_editing` set to `true`?